# AppInsights tile with single metric

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-dashboard

How can I make a single tile 1x1 with a single metric in it?

Some of the default tiles that come with the dashboard show a single metric such has user count. How can I make my own metric that is shown?

Eg, number of exceptions?

Something like this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make my own metric that is shown?

You can create your own metric like Requests, Number of Exceptions, and others in Application Insights and pin them to Dashboard by following the steps below:

- In the Application Insights resource deployed on Azure Portal--> under Monitoring --> Logs --> write your custom query in Kusto.
- After running the above query, you will get the results and you can select the type of chart to use and pin that to the dashboard.

Refer this link to know complete information step by step about [Creating Custom Tiles In Microsoft Azure Application Insights](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/creating-custom-tiles-in-microsoft-azure-application-insights).